# Setting up Python remote debugging in VSCode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am having my remote(ubuntu 16.04) drive mounted on my local system(ubuntu 16.04) so that I can edit the source files by opening them in vscode.

Also, in the integrated terminal I can ssh to remote system and run the program using remote python interpreter which is installed on virtual environment like:

```
$ssh username@remoteip    
$workon remotevirtualenv
(remotevirtualenv)$python source.py
```

I want to enable remote debugging so that if I run the debug/run the remote files, the vscode which is installed on my local system uses my remote python interpreter.

I went through the docs suggesting the use of ptvsd extension(which asks to have 2 copies of source files one on local, another one server) but I am not sure how to configure it in this scenario.
Appreciate the help. Thanks.

**Edit 1:**
As, I said I have gone through the docs but I am not clear how to configure in this scenario. e.g. docs say

> 2. In the **source code on both computers**, add the following lines, replacing my_secret with the appropriate passphrase to authenticate
>      remote debugging, and replacing address with the appropriate IP
>      address (or localhost) and port number:

```
ptvsd.enable_attach("my_secret", address = ('0.0.0.0', 3000))
```

But I have only one copy of source file i.e. on remote system. I have just mounted it on my local file system. So, should I give my local ip address or it should be remote system ip and which port number should I use as I am having only one copy of source and hence ptvsd, how is it going to communicate.
Also, in the configuration, what should I use for `localRoot` location and `remoteRoot` location.

```
 3. {
     "name": "Attach (Remote Debug)",
     "type": "python",
     "request": "attach",
     "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
     "remoteRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
     "port": 3000,
     "secret": "my_secret",
     "host": "localhost" 
 }
```

Edit: Thanks to remote development extension in VSCode, remote debugging is super easy now.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/73378057/11107541

Answer (score 2):

You need to put the remote ip address in both `ptvsd.enable_attach("my_secret", address = ('remote_ip_address', 3000))` and in `launch.json`:

```
{
  "name": "Attach (Remote Debug)",
  "type": "python",
  "request": "attach",
  "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
  "remoteRoot": "/home/user1/scripts/",
  "port": 3000,
  "secret": "my_secret",
  "host": "remote_ip_address" 
}
```

You also need to change the `remoteRoot` value to the path of the directory where the script is located in the remote machine (e.g. `/home/user1/scripts/`).

Finally, open an ssh connection: `ssh -L 3000:localhost:3000`, run your script in the remote machine and attach the debugger in the local machine.