# vscode python remote interpreter

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, remote-access

By using VSCode (Visual Studio Code) I execute Python code on a local Python (Anaconda) interpreter. Now I would like to set it up so that I am able to execute that code on a remote Python interpreter. 
I have a Linux device which has its own Python and is accessible via ssh.
Is it possible to configure it? If so how?
Thank you.

Comment: I think this is a good place to start: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_remote-debugging.
Here is an SO question on it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47809545/setting-up-python-remote-debugging-in-vscode. May be helpful I just took an quick look.

Answer (score 6):

While Microsoft is working on officially implementing this in VSCode (see: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues/79) I am personally using the following task defined in `tasks.json` for running Python on my remote machine. It contains two tasks: (1) synchronize the code to the remote machine using rsync; (2) execute the code over SSH in the remote interpreter. Note that the execution task `dependsOn` the sync task so that executing the code is always done from the latest local copy.

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "Synchronize Code",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "rsync -axv --exclude-from=rsync-exclude.lst --max-size=5MB \"${workspaceFolder}\" user@hostname:dev/code-sync/",
            "problemMatcher": [],
            "isBackground": true,
            "presentation": {
                "echo": false,
                "reveal": "silent",
                "focus": false,
                "panel": "shared",
                "clear": false
            }
        },
        {
            "label": "Remote Execute",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "ssh -n user@hostname \"source ~/.profile && source /path/to/virtualenv/bin/activate && python ~/dev/code-sync/${workspaceFolderBasename}/${relativeFile}\"",
            "dependsOn": [
                "Synchronize Code"
            ],
            "problemMatcher": []
        }
    ]
}
```

Note that you can also assign a keybinding to executing the task so that you can execute the Python code on the remote with a single keypress. Add to `keybindings.json`:

```
{
    "key": "cmd+shift+r",
    "command": "workbench.action.tasks.runTask",
    "args": "Remote Execute"
}
```

Comment: But this doesn't help with features like auto-complete, right? Because that's also an important implication of builtin remote interpreter. How do you go about solving that? Do you create the same exact environment at local too?

Comment: Also, why are you not using the [sync-rsync plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscode-ext.sync-rsync)?